# Vertical space within chapter label using titlesec

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I am required to have a chapter heading formatted in the following way to obey thesis formatting rules at our institution:

> CHAPTER
>
> 1. Chapter Title

The vertical space between "CHAPTER" and the chapter number will need to be specified explicitly (roughly equal to three carriage returns).  The difficulty is that within titlesec, one may only specify space before/after the label (typically, something like "Chapter 1.") and the title text ("Chapter Title" in the above sample).  Using {CHAPTER \thechapter.} as the label specification in titlesec puts the two elements of the label on the same line and any attempt to insert \vspace* or explicit carriage returns gives compile errors.   Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it would be good to rephrase this question to avoid the word "label" in this context.  "label" is a "loaded concept" in latex, designating an identifier that is used for cross-referencing.  maybe "chapter heading" would get the idea across?

Comment: Your point is well taken, however, the word label is also what is used within the documentation of the titlesec package for the content grouping that typically includes the chapter number.

Comment: oh dear.  well, then, i will assume that simply commenting on the usage will clarify the meaning in case anyone is confused.  thanks for providing the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust font size and the spacing, but this should be the idea:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}
  {2\baselineskip}
  {\large\quad\thechapter. }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\large}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course I find this even worse than the chapter styles provided by a well-known package. `;-)` It means nothing, giving emphasis to the least significant part.

Comment: Thank you!  This approach worked beautifully and I would never have thought of breaking the content apart with the two titleformat commands.  Many thanks!